# Automatic processing on internal company systems with Smart Contracts?

Tags: smartcontracts

I'm very new to blockchain and smart contracts. I have given some thought to how Smart Contracts can help in internal business processes. My consideration is as follows: Let’s assume that a condition in a Smart Contract is not met and therefore a predefined internal company process is initiated.

Question: Is it now possible that this Smart Contract, which is running on the blockchain, automatically executes processes on the company's internal systems (e.g. SAP)? For example, internal processes for a complaint?

Would be very grateful for your answers.

Excuse me for my bad english

Best regards

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit late but now there is aeternity working a fully layer 1 oracles to provide information from the outside world.

A good example here:

https://github.com/aeternity/tipping-oracle-service

Answer (score 2):

It still depends. It is possible with smart-contracts in general(not ethereum). You can check out some Enterprise-Oriented blockchains(like Hyperledger Fabric/Iroha/Sawtooth etc.) - it's possible to achieve what do you want there.

If we are talking about ethereum smart-contracts, the short answer is NO. The problem that smart-contracts are not allowed to iniate any actions by themselves. All the actions must be called by somebody. But here you can see an option: write a web-service which will call smart-contract method once in %period of time%, smart-contract checks self state and make some actions according to this state. Another problem is that smart-contracts in Ethereum are isolated from the outside world. So they even can't use web-services and grab information out of blockchain out of the box. But there are also some solutions(so-called Oracles) like [Oraclize](http://www.oraclize.it/) which can help you to break this barriers.

There are also some blockchains with oracles out of the box like [Aeternity](https://www.aeternity.com/) are coming up.

Wrapping everything up - yes, you can. But it's not that simple